# How do I get Bitcoin sale proceeds into my Bank account?

Tags: transactions

I have received confirmation from Bitcoin Account Services that my trade has been processed and that the sale price was $6,842AUD. How do I get these funds into my Australian Commonwealth Bank account?

Comment: Who are "Bitcoin Account Services"? Do you have a web site address?

Comment: Unsure about web sit address, but email address is info@track.consumer-club8.com

Answer (score 0):

If you were to receive a certain amount of Bitcoin into a "wallet" software of your choice, you could move that bitcoin into a cryptocurrency exchange such as [coinbase](https://coinbase.com) or [gemini](https://gemini.com). From there you can add a bank account to your account and sell your Bitcoin by placing a sell order.

As an aside, I have never heard of "Bitcoin Account Services" and a google search does not yield any results. Bitcoin does not belong to any company and transactions within Bitcoin are not controlled by any entity. The Bitcoin network is fully autonomous and can only be interacted with by running certain software that can only ask certain questions.